# Getting a crash on doInBackground() line on client.execute(httpGet). Why?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, crash, thread-safety

Crash is: `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`

Why I am getting a crash on the `HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);` line here? Does it have something to do with my `ThreadPolicy`?

From my fragment I call this:

```
new ReadJSONFeedMainTask().execute(urlString);

....

private class ReadJSONFeedMainTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return Helper.readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's called here:

```
   public static String readJSONFeed(String URL) {

    ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);

    String numberValue = URL.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(numberValue);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
1   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
2   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
3   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
4   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
5   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
6   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
7   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
8   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
9Caused by: com.splunk.mint.network.util.DelegationException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to 50-89-72-86.res.bhn.net/50.89.72.86 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
10  at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:62)
11  at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke(Delegator.java:45)
12  at com.splunk.mint.network.socket.MonitoringSocketImpl.connect(MonitoringSocketImpl.java:118)
13  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
14  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
15  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
16  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
17  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
18  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
19  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
20  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
21  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
22  at com.sortitapps.movies.Helper.readJSONFeed(Helper.java:1282)
23  at com.sortitapps.movies.MainFragment$ReadJSONFeedMainTask.doInBackground(MainFragment.java:680)
24  at com.sortitapps.movies.MainFragment$ReadJSONFeedMainTask.doInBackground(MainFragment.java:678)
25  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
26  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
27  ... 4 more
28Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to 50-89-72-86.res.bhn.net/50.89.72.86 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
29  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
30  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
31  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
32  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
33  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
34  at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:56)
35  ... 20 more
36Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
37  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
38  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
39  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
40  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: And where´s your Asynctask?

Comment: The error is - java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to 50-89-72-86.res.bhn.net/50.89.72.86 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Sounds like your phone/emulator just can't access that URL for some reason (network problem, no access to internet at all, the server is not responding??)

Comment: Thank you @deive I didn't even think about that line. Is there a proper way to handle a timeout on a connect like this?

Comment: Normally you would implement retries for network calls, where you sleep for some time (probably with backoff to sleep longer for each try).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty clear, the end of the stack trace indicates Connection timed out. Your server is unreachable.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, someone else pointed that out, my eyes just were focused on the part of the stack trace where my code was. What is the proper way to handle a timed out connection in this code?

Comment: Timeout is in fact a java.net.ConnectException which is an IOException but in your case, it has triggered a com.splunk.mint.network.util.DelegationException (I don't know splunk). This one was not handled in your try catch block.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem after updating from BugSense to Splunk Mint and there was nothing wrong with my code. After I commented out Splunk.init(...) method invocation everything started to work again. Problem was occuring only on HTC devices and with Splunk Mint enabled - all calls of HttpClient#execute()  method were throwing DelegationException. Not sure if this is your case but maybe my answer will help someone with the same problem as mine.

Comment: This is the correct source of the issue.  The Splunk lib has a feature called "Network Monitoring" which apparently is buggy, and causes any network failures to throw their DelegationException.

More info is buried in their docs: http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintSDKs/latest/SplunkMINTSDKs/DisablenetworkmonitoringforAndroid

You can disable it by calling `Mint.disableNetworkMonitoring()` immediately before your call to `Mint.initAndStartSession()`

Comment: What version were you using of their lib? and why is it buggy from your experience ?

Comment: I think also it got reported but do not case real crash for the app.

Answer (score -2):

You should use Asynctask for any work with server, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: He is using AsyncTask

Comment: @Selvin this code was added by the author later, after my answer.

Comment: And what is the title of the question?